# using GEB / Groovy how to verify text with duplicate id, class, etc tags?

Tags: groovy, geb

I have a modal which I need to confirm is displayed or the text is present. However, this modal has duplicate id, class tags (used in other code). For example, to verify the text "Incorrect selection, please try again.Please select the US logo." the id and class are not unique tags?

```
<div id="errorMessagePanel" class="errorContainer yui-module yui-overlay yui-panel" style="visibility: inherit; width: 350px;">
    <div class="hd" id="flyoutHd" style="cursor: auto;">Shopping Status</div>
    <div class="bd alignLeft" id="flyoutBd">Incorrect selection, please try again. Please select the US logo.</div>
<a class="container-close" href="#">Close</a></div>
```

[image]

Comment: They seem to have different IDs. `hd` Vs `bd`

Comment: yes hd and bd id's differ, but what I meant is that those same id's are used elsewhere on the entire page. i.e. they are copied and not unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following to get the element by its text:

```
static content {

    incorrectSelection { find("div", text: "Incorrect selection, please try again. Please select the US logo.") }

}
```

And then assert it's displayed:

```
assert incorrectSelection.displayed
```

Also if you find multiple elements being returned because of identical selectors you could rely on it's position in the returned array to check a particular element:

```
static content {

  flyOuts { $("#flyoutBd") }

}
```

then:

```
assert.flyOuts[0].displayed
```